# Eliminar elemento que se encuentra dentro de SVG desde javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

Como puedo eliminar el elemento `"#circulo"` que se encuentra en el `svg` `"#svg1"`, desde `Javascript`?

```html
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circulo" cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: ¿La respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('circulo').remove();
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circulo" cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/>
</svg>
```